# Find the value of :

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the value of:
$$2^{\frac {1}{4}}\cdot 4^{\frac {1}{8}}\cdot 8^{\frac {1}{16}}\ldots \infty$$

My Attempt:

Let,
$$x= 2^{\frac {1}{4}}\cdot 4^{\frac {1}{8}}\cdot 8^{\frac {1}{16}}\ldots \infty$$
$$x=2^{\frac {1}{4}}\cdot 2^{\frac {1}{4}}\cdot 2^{\frac {3}{16}}\ldots \infty$$

How do I procees further?

Comment: Apply $\log_2$ to the original quantity and you'll end up with arithmetic-geometric series.

Comment: Why the Down-vote?

Comment: If you are asking me, I did not down-vote.

Comment: @Lohith-Kumar, I didn't say you.

Comment: I didnt downvote but your attempt is very less attempted that may be a reason.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose that's an infinite product, and the general term seems to be $\;a_n=\left(2^n\right)^{1/2^{n+1}}\;$ , so:

$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(2^n\right)^{1/2^{n+1}}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty\left(2^{\frac n{2^{n+1}}}\right)=2^{\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^{n+1}}}$$

but now: for $\;|x|<1\;$ we have

$$\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\implies\frac1{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n-1}\implies\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nx^{n+1}$$

and now just substitute ...

Comment: Let me upvote your answer.so someone very good like jack or dr mv or someone with good reputation solves our problem.

Comment: @Ar Thanks. Yes, perhaps someone else can intervene in this, yet I propose you to at least do the product of the first three and then the first four products of the infinite product. This should already now make crystal clear that your answer and Farrukh's cannot be correct.

Comment: @DonAntonio, Could you please tell me what concepts have you used in solving this??

Comment: @AlbertEinstein The first two steps are, I hope, clear: two of exponents' rules. The second line comes from power series/Taylor series: the first one is the very well known development of geometric series, and after the first $\;\implies\;$ we *differentiate* both sides, the right one termwise (we're allowed to do so within the convergence interval), and then it is only multiplication by $\;x^2\;$ in both sides. The final step isn't shown but it is trivial: substitute $\;x=\cfrac12\;$ .

Comment: @Don i have been doing very silly mistake. You can see Nick's comment so yes $2$ is the correct answer.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar Great. Many times it is usually something elementary that blind us. It doesn't matter, as apparently the OP and other two upvoted that answer from the beginning. Sometimes it is really amazing to observe how some people are so careless and/or so devoid of critical skills than they like automatically upvote..or downvote.

Answer (score 3):

Lets only see the powers they are as follows. $\frac {1}{4},\frac {2}{8},\frac {3}{16} $
 Now using laws of indices we need to evaluate $S=\frac {1}{4}+\frac {2}{8}+\frac {3}{16}+... $which is an AGP. Thus we have $\frac {S}{2}=\frac {1}{8}+\frac {2}{16}+\frac {3}{32}+... $ thus subtracting $\frac {S}{2}=\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{16} $ its a GP . So $S=1 $. Hence the original product is $2^1=2$

Comment: If you multiply the first, only-shown, three factors, you already get $\;2^{1/4}\cdot4^{1/8}\cdot8^{1/16} =1.61...>1.587...=\sqrt[3]4\;$ , and since each factor in the infinite product is greater than $\;1\;$ , I don't think this is correct. Slightly surprisingly (as it has lots of bugs), in this WA agrees with my answer, which is, by what I showed, $\;2^1=2\;$ . I think the mistake here, just like in the other answer which is not the one I posted, is in how the infinite sum is done.

Comment: But if you calculate the AGP you get $2/3 <1$ but as it is raised to 2 it is >1. Can you explain further where the problem can be?

Comment: Also if each term is greater than 1 then product should diverge.

Comment: @Ar Sorry, I don't know what AGP is. I know arith. or geom. progressions: AP or GP. I don't get your question.

Comment: Why would an infinite product with all factors bigger than 1 to diverge? A product $\;\prod(1+a_n)\;$ converges iff the series $\;\sum\log(1+a_n)\;$ converges...

Comment: @Ar Anyway, did you carry on the multiplication of the given first three factors ?

Comment: @Ar Using the well known criterion, we get that
$$\prod_{n=1}^\infty 2^{\frac n{2^{n+1}}}\;\;\text{ converges}\;\iff\sum_{n=1}^\infty\log\left(2^{\frac n{2^{n+1}}}\right)=\log2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^{n+1}}\;\;\;\text{converges}$$and the last series is clearly convergent...

Comment: Now we have a serious problem the value of $\frac {1}{4}+\frac {2}{8}+...=\frac {1}{4}$ So the  value is $2^(0.25)=1.2$

Comment: @Ar First, there are too little summands in that sum of yours for me to know *what series* you're summing, but **if you mean** the series that in the exponents of my answer, it is $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac n{2^{n+1}}=\frac{1/4}{1/4}=1$$

Comment: @Ar Anyway it doesn't really matter: the OP seems to have upvoted you and at least someone else did, too. Let us let him  write down this answer...:)

Comment: @DonAntonio Here, AGP  means "Arithmetic-co-Geometric Progression"

Comment: The sum of the geometric series $\frac {1}{4}+\frac {1}{8}+\frac {1}{16} + \dots $ is $\frac{a}{1-r} = \frac{1/4}{1 -1/2}= \frac{1}{2}$, so $S=1$.